# can't get Woocommerce billing phone inside input field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce, contact-form-7

I have a CF7 form and need to get *Woocommerce billing phone number* and display it inside phone field on page load using jQuery function. I used this code in header area:

```
// Get billing_phone_number On Quote Form

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#mk-order-tel').val("<?php echo get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'billing_phone', true ) ?>");
    });
```

But it returns raw php code ( `<?php echo get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'billing_phone', true ) ?>` ) instead of phone number; when I use same php code directly in php files of Woocommerce it works correctly. What should I do to run a php syntax through the jQuery?

**EDIT**

---

To escape of above issue, I tried to get data by using ajax but this method does not work too:

in functions.php :

```
/* Get Customer Phone Number */

function my_ajax_handler(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $phone = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'billing_phone', true );
     ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
    jQuery('#mk-order-tel').val("<?php echo json_encode($phone); ?>");
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_call_my_ajax_handler', 'my_ajax_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_call_my_ajax_handler', 'my_ajax_handler' );


function my_quote_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/quote.js', array('jquery') );
  wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_quote_scripts' );
```

in quote.js :

```
jQuery.ajax({
    
    type:"POST",
    url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
    data: { 'action': 'call_my_ajax_handler' }
    
})
```

What else can I do ?

Comment: What does `<?php echo get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'billing_phone', true ) ?>` outputs? Did you make sure it outputs a phone number? What if if actually outputs something else like an error? -- There is no issue with the JS you posted.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I used `echo get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'billing_phone', true )` directly in php file of same page and it works correctly. I had placed jQuery in site header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply using this code in *functions.php* of child theme can fetch customer phone and display inside input text field :

```
/* Get Customer Phone Number On Quote Form */

function my_jquery_var() {
    if ( $yourtel = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'billing_phone', true ) ) { 
        
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        var yourTel = "' . $yourtel . '";
        document.getElementById("mk-order-tel").value = yourTel;
        </script>' . "\n";
        
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_jquery_var' );
```

**Note**: JavaScript should be in footer area.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, you're getting an exception because of quotes

```
const tel = <?php echo get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'billing_phone', true ) ?>;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#tel').val(tel);
});
```

Or you can just replace single quotes to double

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#tel').val("<?php echo get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'billing_phone', true ) ?>");
    });
```

Comment: both display `<?php echo get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'billing_phone', true ) ?>` inside field instead of phone number; it seems php code needs some modifications.

Comment: Please check if you're doing all this in a file with `.php` extension

Comment: I used `echo get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'billing_phone', true )` directly in php file of same page and it works correctly. I had placed jQuery in site header.